# Fundamental lemma for variational calculus in dual space

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the following problem:
If $f\in\mathbb{L}^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,E^*)$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)[\phi(x)]\,dx=0$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n,E)$, then $f(x)=0$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I know this lemma for the 'real' case but I don't know how to connect it with the dual space.

Comment: what is $E^*$, $E$, and the respective spaces?

Comment: $E$ is a Banach space and $E^*$ is dual space of $E$ i.e. space of continuous functionals on $E$.

Comment: and those integrals are bochner integrals? - if that is the case, i suggest that you edit that in your question

Comment: Finally, it is not Bochner integral since $f(x)[\phi(x)]\in\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u \in  E$. For every function ${\theta} \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{c}^{\infty } \left({\mathbb{R}}^{n} , \mathbb{R}\right)$ one has ${\theta} u \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{c}^{\infty } \left({\mathbb{R}}^{n} , E\right)$
and

$$0 = \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^{n}}^{}f \left(x\right) \left[{\theta} \left(x\right) u\right] d x = \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^{n}}^{}{\theta} \left(x\right) f \left(x\right) \left[u\right] d x$$

It follows that $f \left(x\right) \left[u\right] = 0$ a.e.

Assuming $E$ is **separable**, let ${\left({u}_{n}\right)}_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable dense family in $E$. It follows that $f \left(x\right) \left[{u}_{n}\right] = 0$ for all $n$
and all $x$ but a set of measure $0$, therefore $f \left(x\right) = 0$ a.e.

Comment: We do not know that E is separable, so maybe we could use Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Comment: @mwrooo I don't see how it could help us. I'm not even sure the result is true in a non separable space. Where does the problem come from?

Comment: It comes from the lecture about strong type operators and Marcinkiewicz Theorem. I can't find any book about Banach-valued functions :/